# Check if value exists in a RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have written a Spark program in python that is working correctly.

However, it is inefficient in terms of memory consumption & I am trying to optimize it. I am running it on AWS EMR and EMR is killing the job for consuming too much memory.

```
 Lost executor 11 on ip-*****: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 11.4 GB of 10.4 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

I believe this memory problem is due to the fact that I am collecting my RDDs (i.e. using .collect() ) at several instances because in later stages, I need to test if some value exists in the list made out of those RDDs or not.

So, currently my code looks like this:

```
myrdd = data.map(lambda word: (word,1))     \
       .reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)   \
       .filter(lambda (a, b): b >= 5) \
       .map(lambda (a,b) : a)          \
       .collect()
```

and sometime later in the code

```
if word in myrdd:
    mylist.append(word)

myrdd2 = data2.map(lambda word: (word,1))     \
       .reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)   \
       .filter(lambda (a, b): b >= 5) \
       .map(lambda (a,b) : a)          \
       .collect()

if word in myrdd2:
    mylist2.append(word)
```

and then I am repeating this pattern multiple times.

Is there a way to do the operation

```
if word in myrdd: 
    do something
```

without collecting the rdd first?

Is there a function like rdd.contains() ?

P.S : I am not caching anything in memory. My spark context looks like this:

```
jobName = "wordcount"
sc = SparkContext(appName = jobName)

......
......

sc.stop()
```

Comment: do not use .collect() it will bring all the data to driver which will create a problem if you have larger data set.  use myrdd2.foreachRDD and check whether the value present

Comment: word  = sc.broadcast([w1,w2,w3])
valuepresent  = myrdd.filter{lambda x : x in word}  something like this this will also one workaround i would think

Answer (score 5):

Error message from YARN says that `collect` is not a problem because your executors (and not a driver) have memory problems.

First, try to follow the error message suggestion and boost `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` - when running pyspark on YARN you can tell YARN to allocate a little bigger containers for the python workers processes memory.

Next, look at operations that executors require large amounts of memory for. You use `reduceByKey`, maybe you can increase number of partitions to make them smaller in terms of memory used. Look at `numPartitions` parameter: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.reduceByKey

Finally, if you want to check if rdd contains some value then just filter by this value and check it using `count` or `first`, for example:

```
looking_for = "....."
contains = rdd.filter(lambda a: a == looking_for).count() > 0
```

Comment: Thank you. Does having a lot of RDDs put a strain on executors? For eg. if I  do something like myrddalias = myrdd, does it put additional strain on memory or is that alright?

Comment: it just copies the reference, rdds itself won't be cloned

Comment: The problem is that looking_for is a RDD and when I do a filter on another RDD it shows me an error saying that I cannot put one transformation inside another. Looking_for is a list and I want to prune my rdd on the basis of a certain value existing in the looking_for rdd or not. The exact error - Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations;